# Mercurial does not show modified file

Tags: xaml, mercurial

I've been working with Mercurial (on windows and using TortoiseHg) for some time now, but today I experienced something I just do not understand.

I'm sure, that I've made some modifications to a file (view.xaml). When I manually compare the local file with the one committed to the repository, I can identify the modifications. But when I do a `hg status` it does not show any modified files...

First thing I checked was, that I had actually saved my work. While doing this, I noticed, that in the windows explorer, it showed the file as modified for just a short time (like 10-20 seconds). Then it changed again and showed as unmodified.

Second thing I checked was the ignore list and view.xaml is not on the ignore list.

Can anyone enlighten me, as to why Mercurial does not show this file as modified?

Comment: Does `hg log -r .` show what you think the last commit should have been?

Comment: Did you only modify whitespaces and you are setup to ignore them? Also, try `hg debugrebuildstate`, to force mercurial to rebuild its internal state. Don't worry, this is safe.

Comment: @duplode: `hg log -r` does indeed show what the last commit is (or what I believe it should be).

Comment: @Vince: I'm unfamiliar with `hg debugrebuildstate`. As far as I can tell, it doesn't do anything in my setup. At least, the command didn't solve the issue

Comment: Try issuing a `hg verify` to check for corruption. Also, you are apparently on TortoiseHg, what happens when you shelf and un-shelf the file?

Comment: @Vince You are absolutely right, I'm using a TortoiseHg. Thought I mentioned that in OP, but apparently I didn't (will edit to mention in a second).
`hg verify` shows me a number of files, changesets and total revisions, but the numbers doesn't seem off to me.
How can I shelf and un-shelf the file, when it doesn't show as modified?

Comment: Right, you can't, sorry... Issue a `hg status -i` and confirm that the  file is not in the list.

Comment: I can confirm, that the file still is not on the list.

Comment: Your repo seems sane, the next step would be to move the file away from the repo's folder, run `hg status` to refresh the state (and validate that the file has been removed!), and bring it back before refreshing it again.

Comment: @Vince Sorry about not responding - I've been away during the Easter. I tried to remove the file from the repository and adding it again. Now it finally showed up as modified.
Thanks so much for your time and effort